# A question on the 2-norm defined by $||x||_2=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

A question on the 2-norm defined by $||x||_2=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2}$

I am trying to prove the triangle inequality of this norm. So far I have that:

\begin{align}
||x+y||_2^2&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i+y_i|^2\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(|x_i|+|y_i|)^2\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2+2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i||y_i|+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2
\end{align}

I want to know if i can now say that:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2+2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i||y_i|+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2 &\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2+2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|y_i|+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2\\
&=||x_i||_2^2+2||x||||y||+||y||_2^2
\end{align}

Note that $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies not in what you are trying to prove, but what you say follows; namely, in your last equality
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \neq \|x\|.$$
On the other hand, for $p = 2$ your space is an i____ p______ space, and in such a space there is an inequality you might have heard of which gives you precisely the result you desire. (Hint: view these as vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Comment: Cauchy Swartz? So $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i||y_i| \leq ||x||||y||$?

Comment: Yes, because $\|x+y\|_2^2 = (x+y, x+y) \leq \|x\|_2^2 + 2|(x,y)| +  \|y\|^2_2 \leq \|x\|^2_2 + 2\|x\|_2\|y\|_2 + \|y\|_2^2 = (\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2)^2.$